# How to exempt certain resource from custom authorization in AWS API Gateway ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have configured custom authorization in API gateway for a proxy resource but my requirement is to exempt few APIs from authorization, but I don't want to configure a new API in API gateway because I'm trying to design a proxy through API gateway.

For Example, the API  /server/ver1.0/rest/{proxy+}, this is my REST API configured in API gateway which goes through custom authorizer and then if it's successful then it invokes backend http service.

But I would like to exempt the API - /server/ver1.0/rest/acc/reg  from authorization.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this directly answers the OP since we do not proxy our requests to a backend API but use Lambda for all API calls, but we still need to authorize only part of our API. This is how we've done it:

We have an API deployed with SAM and in this project we use a custom Authorizer for most of the api.

```
MonitorApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,POST,GET,PATCH,DELETE'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      StageName: !Ref AppStage
      GatewayResponses:
        DEFAULT_4xx:
          ResponseParameters:
            Headers:
              Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "'*'"
              Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: LambdaTokenAuthorizer # This authorizer is used on the API
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
        Authorizers:
          LambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizeFunction.Arn
            Identity:
              Header: Authorization
              ReauthorizeEvery: 300
```

For some resources that we need to make publicly available we override this on the function level, like this:

```
  SystempingFunction: # Systemping service in API
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: monitor/
      Handler: systemping.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: 20
      Events:
        SystempingEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE # Turn off Authorization for this function
            Path: /systemping
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref MonitorApi
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I have solved the issue the same way I described in my question,

As there is no way that AWS gives any programmatic way to omit a specific condition, we are left with below options :

1. Create a separate API - In this way, AWS would give a preference
   to more specific API than a generic one i.e. API 
    `/server/ver1.0/rest/acc/reg` would be given a preference to 
   `/server/ver1.0/rest/{proxy+} 2)`
2. Modify custom authorizer lambda
       function to check each and every URL pattern, but this makes lambda
       custom auth much complex and less maintainable.

I have adopted the first option as its more cleaner and easier to maintain, moreover I didn't want to pollute my lambda custom authorizer with various URL patterns

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the custom authorizer is a lambda function, implying that your API Gateway is a proxy integration with Lambda - you could do it in the lambda function.

Depending on the resource you are requesting, eg :
/acc/reg - you can detect this in the lambda function and bypass authentication.
For all other resources you can go through the custom authorization process.

You could define variables to store your secure vs insecure resources, match those against the request

```
var insecureApis = '/hello,/acc/reg';
var secureApis = '/account/me';

var path = event.path;

if(secureApis.includes(path)){
    //perform custom auth and proxy request
} else {
   // just proxy
}
```

Comment: Thanks mailtobash, currently I have used a separate API in api-gateway and disabled the authorizer in method request configuration but the ideal solution would be to disable the custom authorizer at run-time for specific Url, but it seems the AWS api-gateway doesn't support it as of now.

Comment: Have you found any other solution than creating a separate API? Now it's 2019 and maybe there is some new feature around there...

Comment: @Franco, token-based-authorizer lambda is still the approach that's valid, it's quite flexible. There is also IAM based Authorization approach where only users with certain IAM roles can invoke API gateway.

Answer (score 0):

My use case is a little bit different, I'm using SAM and my Gateway is a HttpApi but I think it can apply to this scenario also.... so here's the entry you need to disable Auth on a specific API endpoint in your template:

```
  yourFunctionName:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/mycode.handler
      Description: Get some data
      FunctionName: getData
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            ApiId: yourHttpApiGatewayRefHere
            Path: /data
            Method: GET
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
```

The important section is

> Auth:  Authorizer: NONE